# Python numpy argsort

Tags: python, list, sorting, numpy

Suppose I have the following lists

```
['foo', '333', 32.3]
['bar', 4.0]
['baz', '555', '2232',  -1.9]
```

I want to be able to sort this via the last element (float)

```
['baz', '555', '2232',  -1.9]
['bar', 4.0]
['foo', '333', 32.3]
```

In ascending order

```
count_array = np.array([('foo', '333', 32.3),('bar', 4.0),('baz', '555', '2232', -1.9)], dtype = np.object)

idx = np.argsort(count_array[:, 1])

print(count_array[idx])
```

I want to be able to sort a 2-D list by comparing its last element. This code ONLY works if the sublists are the same length.

How can I get it to work for variable length sublists?

The problem is this line `idx = np.argsort(count_array[:, 1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use plain `lists` here, when you create a `numpy.array` with sub-lists of different lengths (or different data types in your `array`) you get an `array` of type `object`, which lacks many useful `numpy` features and is rarely a good idea to implement.

```
x = [['foo', '333', 32.3],
     ['bar', 4.0],
     ['baz', '555', '2232',  -1.9]]

result = sorted(x, key=lambda k : k[-1], reverse=True)
```

Result:

```
>>> result
[['foo', '333', 32.3], ['bar', 4.0], ['baz', '555', '2232', -1.9]]
```